# close form1 & open form2

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I used two forms in my windows application that they aren't my main form.
Now I want to close form1 and open form2.
How to I do this.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this once for my project, to close one application and open another application.

```
    System.Threading.Thread newThread;
    Form1 frmNewForm = new Form1;

   newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(frmNewFormThread));
this.Close();
        newThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        newThread.Start();
```

And add the following Method. Your newThread.Start will call this method.

```
    public void frmNewFormThread)()
    {

        Application.Run(frmNewForm);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Hiding and Showing Forms](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_C_Sharp) for a good example of various techniques.

Major points include:

- Creating a C# Application Containing
  Multiple Forms
- Understanding Modal
  and Non-modal Forms
- Writing C# Code to Display a Non-Modal Form
- Writing C# Code to Display a Modal Form
- Hiding Forms in C#
- Closing Forms in C#